# Inverse laplace transform of $s^{n-1}e^{-rb\sqrt{s^{n}+\alpha}}$

Tags: laplace-transform

How can I find the inverse laplace transform of the following function? Is is possible to solve it analytically?

$$s^{n-1}e^{-rb\sqrt{s^{n}+\alpha}}$$